# How to write to a text file using iteration?

Tags: python, file-io, iteration

My code does not write to a file, what am I doing wrong? I am trying to program to continue to ask for products until the user does not enter a product code. I want all products to be saved in the file.

```
    store_file = open("Database.txt", "w")
    NewProduct = ""
    while NewProduct != False:
        contine = input("Press 1 to enter a new product press 2 to leave: ")
        if contine == "1":
            print("Enter your product information")
            information = []
            product = input("What's the product code: ")
            information.append(product)
            description = input("Give a description of the product: ")
            information.append(description)
            price = input("Enter price of product: ")
            information.append(price)
            information = str(information)
            clean = information.replace("]","").replace("[","").replace(",","").replace("'","")

          store_file.write(clean)
   
         elif contine == "2":
         NewProduct = False
    
        else:
          print("Your input is invalid")
    store_file.close
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Makes a huge difference; on Py2, this code is guaranteed to say all inputs are invalid. We need to know the actual error (or lack thereof) to be sure though.

Comment: I'm using python 3. no errors come up but the problem is the database.txt file is created but doesn't contain any data.

Answer (score 0):

I got the program working with the following adjustments. See comments for explanations:

```
store_file = open("Database.txt", "w")
NewProduct = ""
while NewProduct != False:
    continue = raw_input("Press 1 to enter a new product press 2 to leave: ") 
    #Changed to raw_input because input was reading in an integer for 1 rather than a 
    #string like you have set up. This could be specific to my IDE
    if continue == "1":
        print("Enter your product information")
        information = []
        product = raw_input("What's the product code: ")
        information.append(product)
        description = raw_input("Give a description of the product: ")
        information.append(description)
        price = raw_input("Enter price of product: ")
        information.append(price)
        information = str(information)
        clean = information.replace("]","").replace("[","").replace(",","").replace("'","")

        store_file.write(clean + "\n") 
        #Added a line break at the end of each file write


    elif contine == "2":
        NewProduct = False

    else:
        print("Your input is invalid")
    store_file.close() #Added parentheses to call the close function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers I have now been able to resolve and improve my code thanks to your responses. I am using python 3 and new to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem here is that you're using Python 2, and `input` isn't doing what you think it does. In Python 2, `input` `eval`s the input as if it were Python source code, so if someone enters `2`, it's going to return the `int` value `2`, not `"2"`. In Python 2, you want to use `raw_input`, always (`eval`-ing random user input not being secure/reliable).

Also, while on CPython (the reference interpreter) files tend to naturally close themselves when they go out of scope, you made an effort to `close`, but forgot to actually *call* the `close` method; `store_file.close` looks up the method without calling it, `store_file.close()` would actually close it. Of course, explicit `close` is usually the wrong approach; you should use a `with` statement to avoid the possibility of forgetting to close (or of an exception skipping the `close`). You can replace:

```
store_file = open("Database.txt", "w")
...
store_file.close()
```

with:

```
with open("Database.txt", "w") as store_file:
    ... do all your work that writes to the file indented within the with block ...
... When you dedent from the with block, the file is guaranteed to be closed ...
```

There are other issues though. What you're doing with:

```
information = str(information)
information = information.replace("]","").replace("[","").replace(",","").replace("'","")
```

is terrible. I'm 99% sure what you really wanted was to just join the inputs with spaces. If you switch all your `input` calls to `raw_input` (only on Python 2, on Python 3, `input` is like `raw_input` on Python 2), then your `list` is a list of `str`, and you can just `join` them together instead of trying to stringify the `list` itself, then remove all the `list`-y bits. You can replace both lines above with just:

```
information = ' '.join(information)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers I have now been able to resolve and improve my code thanks to your responses. I am using python 3 and new to it.